# Make part of an input field uneditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a dropdown with a list of countries. When the user selects a country from the dropdown a `change` event is triggered and I use a `switch` statement to detect the value selected and add the area code of the country to another input box for the user to enter their phone number.

the problem is that I can't figure out a way to make the area code uneditable. Ideally when the user focuses on the phone input they cannot delete the area code.

Heres an example of my code thus far:

```
//Detect the selected option in dropdown (UK By default)
    $("select[name='country-name']").change(function () {
        var country = $(this).val();
        switch (country) {
            case 'United Kingdom':
                $("input[name='phone-name']").val('+44');
                break;
            case 'Ireland':
                $("input[name='phone-name']").val('+353');
                break;
            case 'France':
                $("input[name='phone-name']").val('+33');
                break;
            case 'Spain':
                $("input[name='phone-name']").val('+34');
                break;
        }
    });

    //When focus on phone Number you cant edit the area code
    $("input[name='phone-name']").focus(function(){
        alert('edit phone');
    });
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Country</label>
        <span>
            <select name="country-name">
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                <option value="France">France</option>
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
        <div>
            <span>
            <input type="text" name="phone-name" value="+44" size="40" maxlength="80" minlength="7"></span><i class="fa fa-times hide"></i><i class="fa fa-check hide"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment the code works fine and does input the area code into the phone input box. However a user can then focus on the phone input box and delete the `+xxx` or `+xx` (depending on country) if they wish. I'd like to prevent them from doing so.

Any idea would be greatly appreciate.

This is my JSFIddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/6dj7hmvu/

Comment: A convenient way is to separate the part you don't want user to edit to another input. And make that input readonly.

Comment: Yes I was thinkin that, I guess if I can't get it done the above way I'll resort to that, just ideally I'd like to keep it all within the same input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way is to listen to `keydown` event, and decides whether the current focuse  d position is overlapping the fixed area, prevent it if the pressed key will alter the fixed area.

```js
window.onload = function() {


  var length  =  length = $("input[name='phone-name']").val().length;
//Detect the selected option in dropdown (UK By default)
    $("select[name='country-name']").change(function () {
        var country = $(this).val();
        switch (country) {
            case 'United Kingdom':
                $("input[name='phone-name']").val('+44');
                break;
            case 'Ireland':
                $("input[name='phone-name']").val('+353');
                break;
            case 'France':
                $("input[name='phone-name']").val('+33');
                break;
            case 'Spain':
                $("input[name='phone-name']").val('+34');
                break;
        }
        length = $("input[name='phone-name']").val().length;
    });
    
    //When focus on phone Number you cant edit the area code
    //$("input[name='phone-name']").focus(function(){
        //alert('edit phone');
    //});
  
    // Direct keys that is allowed
    var directs =  [
        3, //'Home',
        35, //'End'
        37, //'left'
        39 //right
    ]
    $("input[name='phone-name']").on('keydown', function(e){
        var selectionStart = this.selectionStart;  // The start position of current cursor's select/focus range.
        if (directs.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
          // You may want to add other rules like ctrl+c to allow, 
        } else if (selectionStart < length) { // No action except moving is allow at danger area.
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else if (selectionStart === length &&
                   e.keyCode === 8) {  // Backspace is not allow at length, as it remove char
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Country</label>
        <span>
            <select name="country-name">
                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                <option value="France">France</option>
                <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Phone</label>
        <div>
            <span>
            <input type="text"  name="phone-name" value="+44" size="40" maxlength="80" minlength="7"></span><i class="fa fa-times hide"></i><i class="fa fa-check hide"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have to say this looks really promising! I'll give that a shot and get back to you in next hour @fuyushimoya. Why do you think using the keydown is an ugly solution? Is it from a performance standpoint or? Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: Oh, I may remove that later, because I first think it can't prevent user go to danger zone and use `ctrl + c`, seems I was wrong, however, as you may want user to copy, to go through whole input, you need to add pass rules like `arrow key` and `ctrl + c`, and I'm sometimes too lazy to consider all possibilities :P.

Comment: Another reason is that I remembered I answered some question used [MDN - selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/API/Selection), and as it has experiment tag, but I realized that this question would be safe as we are using [MDN - HTMLTextAreaElement.selectionStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) which has no exp tag on the attr, so its ok.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've accept the answer. I think I'll try and build on it to get it more in tune with what I need but that's 100% the foundations of it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a fake input similar to the following:

```
CSS

<style>
    .fakeInput{
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:3px;
        width:300px;
    }

    .fakeInput span{
        margin-left:10px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
 <p class="fakeInput">+44<span class="contentedit" contentEditable="true" onfocus="this.innerHTML=''"></span></p>
```

**Script**

```
//Detect the selected option in dropdown (UK By default)
    $("select[name='country-name']").change(function () {
        var country = $(this).val();
        switch (country) {
            case 'United Kingdom':
                $(".fakeInput").html('+44');
                break;
            case 'Ireland':
                $(".fakeInput").html('+353');
                break;
            case 'France':
                $(".fakeInput").html('+33');
                break;
            case 'Spain':
                $(".fakeInput").html('+34');
                break;
        }
    });
```

Working fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/8086p69z/4/